# Optimize this vba code to run in a very short time

Tags: vba, for-loop

I have a code below

```
For rptlop = 3 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For sulop = 4 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculated").UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If InStr(LCase(Worksheets("Calculated").Cells(sulop, 2)), LCase(Worksheets("Raw").Cells(rptlop, 1))) >= 1 _
        And InStr(LCase(Worksheets("Calculated").Cells(sulop, 1)), LCase(Worksheets("Raw").Cells(rptlop, 2))) >= 1 _
        And InStr(LCase(Worksheets("Calculated").Cells(sulop, 1)), LCase(Worksheets("Raw").Cells(rptlop, 3))) >= 1 Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw").Cells(rptlop, 5) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculated").Cells(sulop, clmqtr(Worksheets("Raw").Cells(rptlop, 4)))
            Exit For
        End If
    Next sulop
Next rptlop
```

for which I have one function as well

```
Function clmqtr(myqtr) As Long
    Dim suclm As Long
    For suclm = 4 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculated").UsedRange.Columns.Count
        If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculated").Cells(3, suclm) = myqtr Then
            clmqtr = suclm
            Exit For
        End If
    Next suclm
End Function
```

in `rptlop` I have 2900 rows in `sulop` I have 70000+ rows. How can I optimize this code to run in a very short time?

Comment: Can you post a sample file for us to work with?

Comment: you can use `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the beginning of your code and set it back to `True` at the end to disable the screen refreshing while running the macro. This can give amazing performance increase

Answer (score 0):

Two immediate thoughts are to `disable screen updating` as well as `set calculation to manual` prior to executing your code. This prevents excel from refershing the screen and performing calculations until your code has finished.

```
'before your loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'
'   your code here
'

'after your code executes, be sure to turn calculation and screen updating back on
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: One comment: it's a good idea when doing this to add an `On Error GoTo Catch` and `Catch:` block. In case something goes wrong in your code, your application screen will still come back.